# Problem while setting up Flutter in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, installation, sdk

I'm trying to setup Flutter on Android Studio but when I'm running the default counter app present in Flutter, although the project is getting built successfully, while running it is giving an exception and exiting execution.

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1
```

When I run flutter doctor in command prompt, I receive the following:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.959], locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit visit
      https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions.
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] Connected device (1 available)
```

And then when I run flutter doctor --android-licenses, it shows this :

```
Android sdkmanager tool not found (C:\Users\siddp\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager).
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions.
```

I've installed the latest flutter SDK from the official flutter site : https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/releases/stable/windows/flutter_windows_1.17.5-stable.zip

I've also saved the Path variable in the system & user environment variables.
I've also downloaded & installed the Flutter and Dart plugins in Android Studio.
My Android Studio has the latest SDKs and their version is compatible with the virtual device(and physical device as well). I've also downloaded all the tools from the SDK manager.
There is no issue with my Android Studio running a normal Android application; it is only causing a problem for a Flutter app.
I've also tried reinstalling everything(Flutter, Android Studio, even Java) but still I'm unable to get it to execute.
I've also tried troubleshooting with various online solutions from StackOverflow and GitHub among others; I can't link them all as there are many and I've been doing this for the last 5 days.

Every solution is appreciated. Thank You !

Answer (score 0):

(1) Android Studio > SDK Manager > Android SDK > SDK Tools > Uncheck "Hide Obsolete Packages" > Check "Android SDK Tools" (Obsolete) > OK to Install

(2) flutter doctor --android-licenses

Added (3):
Can you check if Android Studio > SDK Manager > Android SDK > SDK Platforms > Is the latest API Level installed?

Comment: Android SDK Tools (Obsolete) are already downloaded & installed. Still, I'm facing the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I also recently setup Flutter, but without Android Studio, by downloading Android SDK directly. So 2 things -

1. `Android sdkmanager tool not found (C:\Users\siddp\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager)`

So, is the sdkmanager present at this location & not detected or not present at all?

2. I think flutter may not have been configured with Android_sdk path.
   So, can you set that -> `flutter config --android-sdk <path-to-android-sdk>`

Post this, try `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

Comment: Okay, so I checked the location :
"(C:\Users\siddp\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager)"
And actually, there's no such directory called 'sdkmanager' in the 'bin' folder. I don't seem to locate the location of my sdkmanager. When I'm checking in Android Studio SDK Manager, it's showing me the path : "C:\Users\siddp\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk".
And if I choose to edit that it shows that "An existing Android SDK was detected" and "Android SDK is up to date."
Please help how to resolve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: sdkmanager is not a directory, but its a batch file. If tools folder is not there, is there anything named cmdline-tools? Else you may need to download it. Under Android folder, is there any occurence of sdkmanager.bat?

Comment: Okay, so I've a tools folder and a cmdline-tools folder and also build-tools and platform-tools folders. So the thing is earlier when I checked, the "sdkmanager.bat" file was present in the cmdline-tools folder and absent from tools folder; so I decided to copy-paste it there, but it wasn't working & now the "sdkmanager.bat" file has somehow vanished entirely from my Android\Sdk folder. Even so, my Android applications(non-flutter) seem to run properly. But, I'm still unable to configure flutter! What should I do now?

Comment: Seems like there is a plain workaround for this issue as I was able to use flutter to build & deploy the app on emulators even if the Android License issue persists. Can you try that once? Also, to fix that issue, replace your tools folder itself with this - https://androidsdkmanager.azurewebsites.net/SDKTools latest version of 26 and when you run flutter doctor next time, you can see the License issue vanishes

Comment: I replaced my tools folder to the one in the above website but after I'm running 'flutter doctor' command, somehow the "sdkmanager.bat" file is getting deleted; I even tried copy-pasting it there but again it was getting deleted. So, it is telling to update or install SDK manager. I even tried the workaround, but when I run the flutter app, it exits every time giving a different error message (exit status) each time; sometimes it says the "gradlew.bat" file in your project folder is missing or not readable; mostly it exits before even running, that is when it is debugging the Gradle. :(

Comment: Oh okay. well, there seems to be a lot of issues with the setup them if there are multiple error messages. So, if not going into each one and fixing it, one option would be to just start from scratch with a fresh Flutter SDK and use Android Studio to get a new copy of the android-sdk. In Android settings, can you also verify the SDK_HOME just in case? Also, in the question, you had mentioned some Env variables. So, if you have manually set them, you can go ahead and remove them as Android Studio sets the required variables internally